# Failing to build Xamarin Android project: An outdated of 'Android SDK Build-tools' is in use

Tags: android, xamarin, visual-studio-2015, xamarin.forms, android-build

I'm trying to compile `Android` project of my `Xamarin Form` solution, and it fails with the following exception:

> An outdated of 'Android SDK Build-tools' is in use which this version of Android Support Library does not support.  You must uninstall any 'Android SDK Build-tools' versions older than 23.0.0 from the 'Tools' section in your 'Android SDK Manager'
>   You also need to install 'Android SDK Build-tools' version 23.0.0 or higher.    Invoice.Android

This happened after I updated some components for using `Telerik`, and `SyncFusion`.

I've tried every suggested solution at [here](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/64760/outdated-sdk-build-tools-when-trying-to-build), including cleaning solution and updating `build tools`, and none of them did any good.

I'm using `Android SDK Manager 24.4.1`, and `build-tools 23.0.3` which apparently are the latest versions.

I've attached a picture of all installed components, please let me know if you need any more information.

[image: Installed packes]

Here's my `packages.config`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<packages>
  <package id="Xamarin.Android.Support.Animated.Vector.Drawable" version="23.3.0" targetFramework="monoandroid44" />
  <package id="Xamarin.Android.Support.Design" version="23.3.0" targetFramework="monoandroid44" />
  <package id="Xamarin.Android.Support.v4" version="23.3.0" targetFramework="monoandroid44" />
  <package id="Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.AppCompat" version="23.3.0" targetFramework="monoandroid44" />
  <package id="Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.CardView" version="23.3.0" targetFramework="monoandroid44" />
  <package id="Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.MediaRouter" version="23.3.0" targetFramework="monoandroid44" />
  <package id="Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.RecyclerView" version="23.3.0" targetFramework="monoandroid44" />
  <package id="Xamarin.Android.Support.Vector.Drawable" version="23.3.0" targetFramework="monoandroid44" />
  <package id="Xamarin.Forms" version="2.3.0.49" targetFramework="monoandroid44" />
</packages>
```

This is the complete `build output`:

> Restoring NuGet packages...
>   To prevent NuGet from restoring packages during build, open the Visual Studio Options dialog, click on the Package Manager node and uncheck 'Allow NuGet to download missing packages during build.'
>   1>------ Rebuild All started: Project: Invoice, Configuration: Debug Any CPU ------
>   1>C:\Users{user}\AppData\Local\Syncfusion\EssentialStudio\14.2.0.26\Xamarin\sample\Forms\Invoice\Invoice\Views\InfoView.xaml.cs(28,17,28,38): warning CS0618: 'Label.Font' is obsolete: 'Please use the Font attributes which are on the class itself. Obsoleted in v1.3.0'
>   1>C:\Users{user}\AppData\Local\Syncfusion\EssentialStudio\14.2.0.26\Xamarin\sample\Forms\Invoice\Invoice\Views\ItemView.xaml.cs(57,13,57,34): warning CS0618: 'Label.Font' is obsolete: 'Please use the Font attributes which are on the class itself. Obsoleted in v1.3.0'
>   1>C:\Users{user}\AppData\Local\Syncfusion\EssentialStudio\14.2.0.26\Xamarin\sample\Forms\Invoice\Invoice\Views\ItemView.xaml.cs(68,21,68,41): warning CS0618: 'Label.Font' is obsolete: 'Please use the Font attributes which are on the class itself. Obsoleted in v1.3.0'
>   1>C:\Users{user}\AppData\Local\Syncfusion\EssentialStudio\14.2.0.26\Xamarin\sample\Forms\Invoice\Invoice\Views\ItemView.xaml.cs(68,44,68,68): warning CS0618: 'Label.Font' is obsolete: 'Please use the Font attributes which are on the class itself. Obsoleted in v1.3.0'
>   1>C:\Users{user}\AppData\Local\Syncfusion\EssentialStudio\14.2.0.26\Xamarin\sample\Forms\Invoice\Invoice\Views\ItemView.xaml.cs(68,71,68,98): warning CS0618: 'Label.Font' is obsolete: 'Please use the Font attributes which are on the class itself. Obsoleted in v1.3.0'
>   1>C:\Users{user}\AppData\Local\Syncfusion\EssentialStudio\14.2.0.26\Xamarin\sample\Forms\Invoice\Invoice\Views\ItemView.xaml.cs(69,25,69,56): warning CS0618: 'Label.Font' is obsolete: 'Please use the Font attributes which are on the class itself. Obsoleted in v1.3.0'
>   1>C:\Users{user}\AppData\Local\Syncfusion\EssentialStudio\14.2.0.26\Xamarin\sample\Forms\Invoice\Invoice\Views\ItemView.xaml.cs(121,17,121,31): warning CS0618: 'Label.Font' is obsolete: 'Please use the Font attributes which are on the class itself. Obsoleted in v1.3.0'
>   1>C:\Users{user}\AppData\Local\Syncfusion\EssentialStudio\14.2.0.26\Xamarin\sample\Forms\Invoice\Invoice\Views\ItemView.xaml.cs(127,17,127,33): warning CS0618: 'Label.Font' is obsolete: 'Please use the Font attributes which are on the class itself. Obsoleted in v1.3.0'
>   1>C:\Users{user}\AppData\Local\Syncfusion\EssentialStudio\14.2.0.26\Xamarin\sample\Forms\Invoice\Invoice\Views\ItemView.xaml.cs(131,17,131,35): warning CS0618: 'Label.Font' is obsolete: 'Please use the Font attributes which are on the class itself. Obsoleted in v1.3.0'
>   1>  Invoice -> C:\Users{user}\AppData\Local\Syncfusion\EssentialStudio\14.2.0.26\Xamarin\sample\Forms\Invoice\Invoice\bin\Debug\XamarinIOInvoice.dll
>   2>------ Rebuild All started: Project: Invoice.Android, Configuration: Debug Any CPU ------
>   2>C:\Users{user}\AppData\Local\Syncfusion\EssentialStudio\14.2.0.26\Xamarin\sample\Forms\Invoice\Invoice.Android\Properties\AndroidManifest.xml : warning XA0101: @(Content) build action is not supported
>   2>C:\Users{}\AppData\Local\Syncfusion\EssentialStudio\14.2.0.26\Xamarin\sample\Forms\Invoice\packages\Xamarin.Android.Support.Vector.Drawable.23.3.0\build\Xamarin.Android.Support.Vector.Drawable.targets(40,5): error : An outdated of 'Android SDK Build-tools' is in use which this version of Android Support Library does not support.  You must uninstall any 'Android SDK Build-tools' versions older than 23.0.0 from the 'Tools' section in your 'Android SDK Manager'
>   2>C:\Users{user}\AppData\Local\Syncfusion\EssentialStudio\14.2.0.26\Xamarin\sample\Forms\Invoice\packages\Xamarin.Android.Support.Vector.Drawable.23.3.0\build\Xamarin.Android.Support.Vector.Drawable.targets(40,5): error : You also need to install 'Android SDK Build-tools' version 23.0.0 or higher.
>   ========== Rebuild All: 1 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 skipped ==========

**UPDATE**

I just updated to `build-tools 24.0.1`, but the error is not going anywhere!

This problem exists only for `Xamarin Form`, I can compile `Android` projects just fine.

Comment: Latest Android SDK `Build-tools = 24.0.1`, `Tools = 25.1.7` (25.2.1)

Comment: Thanks @SushiHangover, I'm not sure upgrading will solve my problem though. The exception is about 23 and used versions are still higher than that.

Comment: Can you add Verbose Build Output? https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/27515/how-to-obtain-diagnostic-build-logs (XS) and http://blogs.msdn.com/b/msbuild/archive/2005/09/29/475157.aspx (VS)

Please also include the Android Support Library version you are trying to use. (Aka your `packages.config` contents should help)

Comment: Go into the folder location of the SDK and delete the old versions manually

Comment: I have done that too! Now I have only one `build-tools` directory. Does it have anything to do with `SDK Platform`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go to your SDK Build-Tools folder and rename the folder to 23.0.3

I had this problem too here : [An outdated of 'Android SDK Build-tools' Error on Xamarin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38817486/an-outdated-of-android-sdk-build-tools-error-on-xamarin/39025289)

Comment: Unfortunately, renaming `Android-6.0` directory to `Androig-23.0.3` didn't solve my problem.

Comment: Do Not rename it to Android-23.0.3 , Use just 23.0.3 without 'Android'

Comment: Then clean the project and rebuild it... it will work Trust me

Comment: Thanks bro, it did the job ;)